# Definition of chromatic class digraph of an $m$-coloured digraph

Tags: graph-theory, definition, directed-graphs

I have to prove that if $D$ is an $m$-coloured digraph, then $K(D) = K \big(C(D)\big)$

Where $C(D)$ is the chromatic transitive closure of $D$, which is a multidigraph with the same nodes and arcs of $D$ plus those arcs of the form $(a,b)$ iff there is a monochromatic directed path from $a$ to $b$ in $D$.

I'm only asking for the definition of $K(D)$, which might be called something like the Chromatic class digraph of a m-coloured digraph.

I know this is a vague definition, but any help would be highly appreciated.